# How to limit download size?

Tags: file, download

The users will be downloading multiple files at a time. The files would be zipped and sent to the user. Since the user base is very large for the application, there will be a limit on the zip size that the user can download at a time (e.g., 50 MB)? What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Are you asking if downloads should be limitted, or how they can be limitted?

Comment: Help on what? deciding on the requirements of your application? This is probably not the best place for that.

Comment: I don't see the connection between download time and session timeout. The session should only be checked at the start of the download. 

It sounds like you haven't sorted out the requirements properly. What are the constraints on bandwidth that you have? Should some users be able to download more than others? Have you thought about bandwidth throttling?

Comment: @Owen: The connection between download size and session timeout is that if they download a large file, then when they go back to use the site the session will have expired.

Comment: My question is if the downloads should be limited?

Comment: A better question to ask would be 'how can I limit downloads' after you have decided whether you want to limit downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with squid: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/reply_body_max_size/